# Get double pointer in SWIG

Tags: c, swig

I have a C API that passes double pointers to structs in its destructors, in order to also null the pointers after the free. For instance:

```
void freeSomething(Something** foo) {
   free(*foo)
   *foo = null
}
```

This pattern follows that of the OpenCV API, among other things.

Unfortunately using SWIG to wrap these functions is a pain, because SWIG creates a type p_Something and a separate type p_p_Something. I then have to write utility functions in the SWIG interface to convert between these types. Essentially for each type I want to free I have to define:

```
%{
#include "something.h"
%}
%inline %{
    void swigFreeSomething(Something* foo) {
        freeSomething(&foo);
    }
%}
```

Is there some way for me to do this or something equivalent for all of my types automatically? Perhaps a different approach altogether?

Comment: could you just write one 'helper' function for swig that returns the address of a void * parameter and call that function with a p_ datatype every time you need a p_p_ datatype - i don't think you need have a reverse function, e.g. p_p_ to p_ which is handy as you can't dereference a void * as you only using p_p_ as a destructor

Comment: What language are you swigging to? I'm concerned about tampering with memory like that, what if the Something is created in the target language? Once free(*foo) has been called, the target Something wrapper has a dangling pointer without SWIG knowing about it. Can you post an example use from the target language?

Comment: @Schollii Java, but I don't call free explicitly, it's called automatically by java's GC when I no longer have any references to the wrapper. i.e. this will be in the destructor of a class defined in SWIG.